# JWPlayer and fancybox giving error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, jwplayer

I stumbled on a small problem with JWPlayer and Fancybox, i have a gallery with photos and videos, and the video item looks like this:

```
<article class="col-md-4 isotopeItem photo">
    <div class="portfolio-item">
        <img src="img/portfolio/videos/thumbs/vid1_thumb.jpg" alt="" />

        <div class="portfolio-desc align-center">
            <div class="folio-info">
                <h5><a href="#">Portfolio name</a></h5>
                <a class="fancybox" data-type="swf" href="js/jwplayer/jwplayer.swf?file=img/portfolio/videos/files/vid1.mp4" title="local video mp4"><i class="fa fa-expand fa-2x"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Whenever i click the anchor it loads a little script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".fancybox").on("click", function(){
        $.fancybox({
        href: this.href,
        type: $(this).data("type")
    }); // fancybox
        return false
    }); // on
}); // ready
```

Then the Fancybox pops up like it should do, but the video doesnt show up,
cus i get an error:

```
"Error loading player: Could not load player configuration"
```

im not sure if this problem is cus i missed something with the player or its something else, but i hope you guys can help me out.

p.s. im not the best at Jquery / Js so go easy on me please.

Comment: could you provide a link or jsfiddle to debug the problem you are facing?

Comment: are you testing localhost? try in a server environment and check your paths are correct

Comment: Do you have a link? Also, maybe this LightBox would be better for you. - https://github.com/emaxsaun/jwbox

Comment: Managed to fix it, paths were incorrect somehow, started working from the server root working now, srill not in IE tho

Comment: Glad you got it working. Do you have a link?

Comment: not yet, ill give it to you when the website is live